# What does 'salvo' mean in this context?

Tags: word-meaning

> WASHINGTON (Reuters) - President Donald Trump backed boycotting American motorcycle manufacturer Harley Davidson Inc on Sunday, the latest **salvo** in a dispute between the company and Trump over tariffs on steel.

According to [Collins dictionary](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/salvo), **salvo** can mean:

> 1. countable noun
>      A salvo is the firing of several guns or missiles at the same time in a battle or ceremony.
> 2. countable noun
>      A salvo of angry words is a lot of them spoken or written at about the same time.

It seems that the definition 2 is more close to this context, but I am not sure how to understand it in this context. Can someone help to elaborate a bit?

The [full source](https://www.yahoo.com/finance/news/trump-backs-boycott-harley-davidson-steel-tariff-dispute-150215038--finance.html).

Comment: Trump and HD have been "firing" at each other in public statements and tweets since HD announced it was moving some production (and therefore jobs) to Europe so HD sales there would not be subject to tariffs imposed by the EU in retaliation for Trump's tariffs on European steel.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is indeed the figurative second definition that is used here.

If you think of the dispute between trump and HD as a battle where verbal shots are fire back and forth, the backing of the boycott is the latest salvo fired.